different anaconda version conflicts on my mac
i installed a intel version of anaconda on my macbook originally, but i forgot and download a arm version of anaconda to update, which begin my nightmare. i cannot use conda and cannot uninstall anaconda to fix the problem and i cannot install mysqldump to backup my database. before i restore my mac, what could i possibly to do?
after the accident, i have tried to update conda but failed. then i tried to uninstall anaconda and reinstall it and failed. after restarting my mac, there is no conda command at all. but my conda still works somehow. i could start it, and open spyder, but i cannot open spyder from terminal cause it cannot find spyder command

Manually Uninstall Anaconda:
1-Run the following commands in the terminal to manually remove Anaconda and its related files:
rm -rf ~/anaconda3
rm -rf ~/.condarc ~/.conda ~/.continuum

2-Clean PATH Variable enter code here
Clean up the PATH variables pointing to Anaconda. Open your ~/.bash_profile, ~/.zshrc, or ~/.bashrc files and remove the lines related to Anaconda.
For example
export PATH="/Users/yourusername/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"

Find and delete these lines, then restart the terminal or run source ~/.bash_profile (or the appropriate file).
Reinstall Conda:
After completing these steps, try downloading and installing the correct version of Anaconda (Intel or ARM) again.
Install mysqldump Using Homebrew:
You can install mysqldump using Homebrew:
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
brew install mysql-client


Looks like an AI-generated answer.
